Fast covariance evaluation for sparse and large-scale non-linear least square problems
A non-linear least squares problem can be formulated as:
$$
\hat{x} = \underset{x}{\mathrm{argmin}}\, \frac{1}{2} ||\varepsilon(x)||^2
$$
where $x$ is the parameters of the problem, and $\varepsilon(x)$ is the normalized residual, which is a non-linear function of $x$.
This problem can be solved using iterative methods, such as the Gauss-Newton algorithm. With a point estimate $\hat{x}$, I want to evaluate the covariance of $\hat{x}$, which is given by the inverse of the Hessian of the objective function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} ||\varepsilon(x)||^2$. The hessian can be approximated as $
H(x) = J^\top(x)J(x),
$
where $J(x)$ is the Jacobian of $\varepsilon(x)$ with respect to $x$. Thus, the covariance of the least square estimate can be computed as
$$
Q = \mathrm{cov}(x) = (J^\top(x)J(x))^{-1}.
$$
Now, for the problem at hand, the dimension of $x$ could reach $10^6$, and the dimension of $\varepsilon$ is around $2\cdot 10^6$. However, $J$ is sparse, and I am only interested in computing the diagonal of $Q$, and approximations of them. Details of $J$ can be found further down.
Here are the methods I have tried:
A. Using sparse matrices in Matlab, the naive way
diag(inv(J'*J))

works surprisingly well for dimensions of $x$ up to $10^4$. However, this computes the full inverse, which is undesirable.
B. Another thing I have tested is the following method

Form the product $A = J^\top J$
Compute the Cholesky decomposition $A = L^\top L$
The diagonal of $Q$ can be computed as $q_i = ||L^{-1}_i||^2$, where $L^{-1}_i$ is the ith column of $L^{-1}$.

Steps 1 and 3 can be computed fast using sparse matrices, but step 2 is still quite slow. Using the incomplete Cholesky decomposition ichol in Matlab improves things, but the problem is still intractable for $10^6$ dimensions.
C. I have tried the sparse approximate inverse approach as well, which computes the diagonal matrix that best approximates the inverse of a PD matrix ($A$). However, the approximation is not good enough for my application.
$J$ has the following block diagonal structure (blue elements are non-zero entries):

which gives a $H$ with the following structure:

The blocks in these matrices are on the order $3\times3$.
The details of the problem can be found in Section 4
